# Why I have multiple shortcuts to the same application?

Tags: 20.04, .desktop, shortcuts

I search for the Skype application in my **`Ubuntu 20.04.1`** and I have got the result as

[image: multiple skype]

As we can see, I have got two Skype shortcuts. How did this happen? Did I do something wrong? How can I get rid of this?

Comment: Look into `~/.local/share/applications` and remove an extra `.desktop` file.

Comment: I couldn't find any duplicate `.desktop` files there. Apart from that, I couldn't even see any *Skype* shortcuts in that directory. @Pilot6

Comment: What about `/usr/share/applications`?

Comment: Wow!!! there you are!!! @Pilot6